# msvcr71.dll file missing on Win Vista when trying to run my java swing application

Tags: java, .net, windows-vista, exe4j

I've done numerous searches and I realize that I can just download this file and install it either in windows/system32 or in the application's directory. My question is, how does this dll generally get installed on Vista? I tried installing the .net framework 3.5 and it didn't get installed with that.

Background:
I'm running a java.jar wrapped as an exe using exe4j.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

msvcr71.dll is the Microsoft Visual C++ Common Runtime for Visual Studio 2003.  Applications developed with VS2003 will usually install this.

Comment: I looked, but I could not find any download links except for the newer 8.0 and 9.0 distributions on Microsoft's Site. It might be hard to find to download from an "official source". Playing "Find the DLL" by installing apps is not fun either!

Comment: I used my handy "Merge Module Finder" and located it in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules\VC_User_CRT71_RTL_X86_---.msm".  So this is the one you want in your installer.

Answer (score 1):

i tried this fix to resolve MSVCR71.dll missing error in Windows 7 X64:
http://backspacetab.com/2011/05/09/msvcr71-dll-windows-7-x64/
Its only for 64Bit users... 32bit users follow the guide here: http://i.justrealized.com/2009/how-to-fix-missing-msvcr71dll-problem-in-windows/
Thanks and enjoy !!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried executing using "java -jar java.jar"?  Does it produce the same result?

Comment: No, when I double click on the jar file, or run java -jar java.jar it works fine. It's just when I run the .exe wrapped around the jar with exe4j. We have to use an exe so using the jar is not an option.

Comment: I have not used exe4j, but from the docs it appears that there is a "path" configuration page on the exe creation wizard where you specify the locations of native libraries.  Perhaps you could add the directory to that list?

Answer (score 0):

Since VS 2003 targeted older versions of .NET and is not a supported development environment on Vista, it's probably only going to get installed on Vista if an application's installer does so.

I don't know if the .NET 1.1 redistributable will install it on Vista, but it's worth a try in a virtual machine.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the .NET 1.1 redistributable but it wouldn't install on Vista.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be related to these Sun bugs -

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6560269
and
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6648440

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest exe4j (version 4.1) solved this issue!